# Infinite-dimensional, countable, rational vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cardinals

Does such a thing exist? More explicitly, can I find a vector space $V$ over $\textbf{Q}$, such that $$\dim_\textbf{Q}V=+\infty$$ and $$\operatorname{card}V=\aleph_0$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $V = \mathbb{Q}^\infty$ which is the set of all rational sequences $(r_1,r_2,r_3,\ldots)$ --- under the operations of coordinate-wise addition and scalar multiplication --- such that the sequence is eventually zero in the sense that $\exists I \ge 0$ such that $r_i = 0$ if $i \ge I$. If you identify $\mathbb{Q}^n$ with the sequences of the form $(r_1,r_2,r_2,...r_{n-1},r_n,0,0,0,...)$, then you have a nested inclusion of vector spaces
$$\mathbb{Q}^1 \subset \mathbb{Q}^2 \subset \mathbb{Q}^3 \subset ...
$$
whose union is $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$. You can then use a simple enumeration to show that $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ is countable, or you can also fall back on the set theoretical theorem saying that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: I am bit confused by your notation. You start by saying that $\mathbb Q^\infty$ denotes the set of *all* rational sequences. And then you say that it is union of $\mathbb Q^n$, which would mean that it is set of rational sequences with *finite support* (i.e., eventually zero).

Comment: My sentence was perhaps overly elongated. Here it is again with some of its clauses replaced by ellipses: "$\mathbb{Q}^\infty$ is the set of all rational sequences..... such that the sequence is eventually zero...". I added some m-dashes to clarify.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry for not reading carefully enough. +1 (This is what I would consider the most natural example.)

Answer (score 3):

Take $V$ to be the vector space ${\mathbb Q}[X]$ of polynomials over ${\mathbb Q}$. It's the union of the countable collection of polynomials of degree at most $n$, each themselves countable, so is countable.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Q}[\pi^n]$$
works